# Delete and add datatables rows

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm updating datatables from a json response by clearing the table and adding the content again.

```
            var tbsorter = $('.tablesorter-js').dataTable();
            tbsorter.fnClearTable(); 

            var obj = JSON.parse(m);

            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {                 
               var arObjData = value                    
              tbsorter.fnAddData(arObjData);        
           });
```

I would prefer to only add and delete rows according to the json response and not clearing the table and then adding it all again.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you'll need them to loop which record in datatable does not exist and add those which will provide you with a very nice low performance :). You better clear and add it again

Answer (score 0):

Serverside processing. Add in your datatble definition something like this:

```
...
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource" : "json_data.php",
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        "dataType": "json",
        "type"    : "POST",
        "url"     : sSource,
        "data"    : aoData,
        "success" : fnCallback
    });
 }
```

...

json_data.php should return your JSON data.